# JSON decode, updating fields and encode it again altered the json construction

Tags: php, utf-8, json

I got the following json code in a mysql cell:

```
{
"0ba9f1d1-787c-4d8e-a820-0c973bbd20fb":  {
    "0":  {
        "value": "Alex"
     }
},
"9a7df867-1c25-4e15-b0dd-1d20031c31fb":  {
    "0":  {
        "value": "Άλέξανδρος Γιόου"
    }
},
"659d5d3d-ac12-4f17-91c0-334fbd4f3538":  {
    "option":  {
        "0": "0",
        "1": "0"
    },
    "select": "1"
  }
}
```

and i want to update some of the values in php. 
I tried with the following code but i am geting some unexpected results.

```
$check = mysql_query("SELECT `elements` FROM `test_zoo_item` WHERE `id` = 34839");
$decodedelements = json_decode($elements, true);
$decodedelements['0ba9f1d1-787c-4d8e-a820-0c973bbd20fb'][0]['value'] = "Test";
$decodedelements['9a7df867-1c25-4e15-b0dd-1d20031c31fb'][0]['value'] = "Γιώργος";
$decodedelements['659d5d3d-ac12-4f17-91c0-334fbd4f3538']['option'][0] = "3";
$newelements = json_encode($decodedelements);
mysql_query("UPDATE `test_zoo_item` SET `elements`='$newelements' WHERE `id`=34839");
```

My updated cell is:

```
{
"0ba9f1d1-787c-4d8e-a820-0c973bbd20fb": [{
    "value": "Alex"
}],
"9a7df867-1c25-4e15-b0dd-1d20031c31fb": [{
    "value": "u00ce...fu0082"
}],
"659d5d3d-ac12-4f17-91c0-334fbd4f3538": {
    "option": ["0", "0"],
    "select": "1"
}
}
```

Is it possible to help so i can solve the following problems?

- `"0":  {"value": "Alex"}` changed to `[{"value": "Alex"}]`
- `"value": "Άλέξανδρος Γιόου"` changed to `"value": "u00c....cfu0082"`
- `"option":  {"0": "0","1": "0"}` changed to `"option": ["0", "0"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array conversion (your first and last example) can be deactivated by using the `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` option. The second example looks like unicode is used for encoding. That can be disabled by using `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`

```
$newelements = json_encode( $decodedelements, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );
```

- [`json_encode()` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)
- [JSON constants in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php)

Comment: the 1st is ok but i now get utf-8 like this: `value":"Î§ÏÎ®ÏÏÎ¿Ï ÎÎ±ÏÎ±Î³ÎºÏÏ"`

Comment: @Alexandros Uh oh... then read this: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: No! Everything to database and html is ok. UTF-8 working without problem before updating its values...

Comment: Maybe is because i already used utf8_encode in a file which i use to get new values? `file_put_contents($datafile, utf8_encode($data));`

Comment: @Alexandros Are those escaped unicode symbol really a problem for you? when using `json_decode()` again, they get resolved to the "real" characters.

Comment: OK! I remove utf8_encode and now its ok. I think that with JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE it was useless! THANK YOU BOTH you and @deceze but i can only accept one answer.

Answer (score 1):

> - `"0":  {"value": "Alex"}` changed to `[{"value": "Alex"}]`
> - `"option":  {"0": "0","1": "0"}` changed to `"option": ["0", "0"]`

That's because a continuously numerically indexed array in PHP is equivalent to a `[]` array in JSON, and `json_encode` encodes it as such. If you want to *force objects*, then [`JSON_FORCE_OBJECT`](http://php.net/json_encode).

> - `"value": "Άλέξανδρος Γιόου"` changed to `"value": "u00c....cfu0082"`

That's because `json_encode` encodes non-ASCII chars to `\u....` escape sequences, which is fine per se. You're then not *SQL escaping* the string though, so MySQL filters the backslashes out. You need to SQL escape the value or use prepared statements.

Comment: Uh oh... start here: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)